# Remove first level of multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I wan't to remove the first levels of identifier [0]. I think there is a function for this to rewrite the following code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [parent_id] => 15
            [status] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [parent_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

and I want like this

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [parent_id] => 15
            [status] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [parent_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )
)
```

I tried with following code, but I want them in the same array. Is there a function for this?

```
        $processed = array();
        foreach($category[0] as $key => $value) {
            $processed[$key] = $value;
        }
Array
(
    [id] => 20
    [parent_id] => 15
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 15
    [parent_id] => 1
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [parent_id] => 0
    [status] => 1
)
```

I figure it out but is there a function for this?

```
$output = array();

while(true) {
// code ..
$processed = array();
foreach($category[0] as $key => $value) {
    $processed[$key] = $value;
}
$output[] = $processed;

//code..
}

print_r($output)
```

Comment: One way would be `$mFinalArray[] = $mArray;
$mFinalArray[] = $mArray2;`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I just edited my question, see my code and output

Comment: Try what i mentioned above. `$mArray` stands for the one array and `$mArray2` for the other one. If you have trouble doing that, please refer your array names so i can give you the exact line. However, you should really read the concept of how arrays work because probably you will use them a lot.

Comment: But I have more than 2 arrays. I want something dinamically

Comment: Do you need a variadic function (or do you know how many arrays you will be merging)? Where are these arrays coming from?  a database result? a file? a preg_match_all()?  In many cases, if you use the trailing `[]` as Antonis advises when you first receive this data, you can eliminate the need for `array_merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want array_merge: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

In your example code, you'd use it like so:

```
$firstArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
        [parent_id] => 15
        [status] => 1
    )
);

$secondArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [parent_id] => 1
        [status] => 1
    )
)

$thirdArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [parent_id] => 1
        [status] => 1
    )
)

$processed = array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray, $thirdArray);
```

If the above approach is impractical, you may do something like:

```
$processed = array();
foreach($category[0] as $key => $value) {
    $processed = array_merge($processed, $value);
}
```